# Summation of a difference of two square-roots

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does a closed form expression exist for

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k}}-\sqrt{1
-\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$

I obtained

$$0.97423066\ln(n)+1.2019463$$

using log regression and it works very well for my (physics) problems but I was wondering if a better solution exists. Is the Euler-Maclaurin method something to look at ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your formula should be true for $n=1$ for instance. It is not. If a kind of asymptotic formula is wanted, then please specify this. And then please show the effort that supports the new claimed result.

Comment: My formula gets closer to the sum for larger n, so asymptotic. However it's good enough for my physics problem as long as n≥20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1+\frac1k} - \sqrt{1-\frac1k} &= \frac{(\sqrt{1+\frac1k} - \sqrt{1-\frac1k})(\sqrt{1+\frac1k} + \sqrt{1-\frac1k})}{\sqrt{1+\frac1k} + \sqrt{1-\frac1k}} \\
&= \frac{\frac2k}{\sqrt{1+\frac1k} + \sqrt{1-\frac1k}} \\
&= \frac{\frac2k}{(1+O(\frac1k))+(1+O(\frac1k))} = \frac1k + O\biggl( \frac1{k^2} \biggr),
\end{align*}
the sum will be asymptotically
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \biggl( \sqrt{1+\frac1k} - \sqrt{1-\frac1k} \biggr) = \sum_{k=1}^n \biggl( \frac1k + O\biggl( \frac1{k^2} \biggr) \biggr) = \ln n + O(1)
$$
with leading coefficient $1$.
I doubt there's a particularly nice form for the constant other than
$$
\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \biggl( \sqrt{1+\frac1k} - \sqrt{1-\frac1k}  - \frac1k \biggr)
$$
(where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant);
but it turns out this sum converges as fast as $\sum \frac1{k^3}$, so even just the first $10^5$ terms already gives $1.01902854$ accurately rounded to that many decimal places.

Comment: Thank you Greg, just as I thought, no nice form so I think I will stick with my log regression for now which agrees with your analysis.

Comment: The constant should be $\color{red}{\gamma}+\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{\infty}} \left( \sqrt{1+\frac1k} - \sqrt{1-\frac1k}  - \frac1k \right)$.

Comment: @Gary good catch x2! fixed

Answer (score 3):

I shall derive a complete asymptotic expansion for the sum as $n\to+\infty$. Note that for $|x|<1$,
$$
\sqrt {1 + x}  - \sqrt {1 - x}  - x = \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \binom{4m}{2m} \frac{{x^{2m + 1} }}{{16^m (2m + 1)}}.
$$
Employing this expansion together with
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = H_n ,\qquad \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^{2m + 1} }}}  = \zeta (2m + 1) - \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^{2m + 1} }}} ,
$$
where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number and $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2), we find
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {\sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{k}}  - \sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{k}} } \right)}  = H_n  - \gamma  + C - \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty  \binom{4m}{2m} \frac{1}{{16^m (2m + 1)}}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^{2m + 1} }}} .
$$
Here
$$
C = \gamma  + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \binom{4m}{2m} \frac{{\zeta (2m + 1)}}{{16^m (2m + 1)}}=1.019028540417608960\ldots,
$$
and $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). It is shown in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-014-9636-x) that
$$
 - \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^{2m + 1} }}}  \sim \frac{1}{{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{2m} }}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(1 - 2^{1 - 2k} )B_{2k} }}{{(2k)!}}\frac{{ (2m + 2k-1)!}}{{(2m)!}}\frac{1}{{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{2k} }}} 
$$
for any $m\ge 1$ as $n\to+\infty$. Here the $B_k$ denote the [Bernoulli numbers](https://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2). Substitution and re-arrangement yield
\begin{multline*}
 - \sum\limits_{m = 1}^\infty \binom{4m}{2m} \frac{1}{{16^m (2m + 1)}}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k^{2m + 1} }}} \\ \sim \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{2k(2k + 1)}}\sum\limits_{m = 1}^k {\binom{4m}{2m}\binom{2k+1}{2m+1}\frac{{(1 - 2^{1 - 2k + 2m} )B_{2k - 2m} }}{{16^m }}} } \right)\frac{1}{{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{2k} }}} ,
\end{multline*}
as $n\to+\infty$. It is shown in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(91)90296-C) that
$$
H_n  - \gamma  \sim \log \left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{(1 - 2^{1 - 2k} )B_{2k} }}{{2k\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{2k} }}} ,
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. Hence, in summary,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {\sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{k}}  - \sqrt {1 - \frac{1}{k}} } \right)} & \sim \log \left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) + C + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{A_k }}{{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{2k} }}} 
\\ & = \log \left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) + C - \frac{1}{{48\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2 }} - \frac{{41}}{{7680\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^4 }} +  \ldots ,
\end{align*}
as $n\to+\infty$, with
$$
A_k  = \frac{1}{{2k(2k + 1)}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^k {\binom{4m}{2m}\binom{2k+1}{2m+1}\frac{{(1 - 2^{1 - 2k + 2m} )B_{2k - 2m} }}{{16^m }}} .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for that wonderful analysis. My problem is a physics one but I simply love the fact that Euler, gamma, harmonics, Bernoulli etc are hidden inside the problem. I get your overall idea and I will work through the details of the algebra.

Comment: You are welcome. You can of course use this approach for any analytic function on the unit disc not just $\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: @Polynomial I noticed you unaccepted my answer. Is there any way I can improve my answer?